# Formatting numbers in D7

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a serialized object in a field. I now need to output a float-value. Since the site has 2 languages (german/english) I now need to format the float-number based on the current language.

```
$value = 123456789.01;
// Language = english
print the_format_function($value); # => 123456789.01

// Lanuage = german
print the_format_function($value); # => 123.345.789,01
```

I'm lookin for `the_format_funtion();`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [format_number API module](http://drupal.org/project/format_number), which may eventually handle this for you. And possibly will make it into [D8](http://drupal.org/node/52153).

For the moment I think the function you are looking for is [number_format()](http://uk.php.net/number_format)

Comment: unfortunately `format_number` is only for D6.

Comment: You can still use the php function number_format()

Comment: Yup… used it. But had to build my own language-logic around it. Was hoping for some stuff that is built into d7.

Comment: I would have thought there would be too. Wordpress does?!?

Comment: For this specific behaviour, creating logic around the number_format() function is the way to go. And note that English-speaking countries use the comma as the decimal mark for the thousands separator, so the example provided was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

There is a number_format function in native php, so you can do in your drupal template:

```
print number_format($value, 2, ',', '.'); # => 123.345.789,01
```

see http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php